# Why does the default Boolean return value influence my tests outcome

Tags: java, boolean

I'm learning Java and while completing exercises I stumbled upon an issue in CodingBats **sameStarChar** program.

I know this is a simple exercise but the logic behind the different outcome is really bugging me.

When I write :

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str) {

    for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '*') {
            if (str.charAt(i - 1) != str.charAt(i + 1))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

All results are OK.

But when I change the code and invert the condition in the `if` block and return `false` as default return value, the code does not work anymore and some test fail:

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str) {

    for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '*') {
            if (str.charAt(i - 1) == str.charAt(i + 1))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can you please tell me why are the outcomes different? I can`t seem to find an exact explanation for this in any book.

Comment: You wonder why you get different results if you make the return value exactly opposite?

Comment: Depends on what you are testing. What tests fail?

Comment: This is not really a Java question but basic Boolean logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pay close attention to what the code is doing, in English:

- Looping across all characters of a string, starting at 1 and going until 1 before its end

  - If the character at a given position *i* is `*`:

    - If the characters a position before and a position after are equal:

      - Return false.
- Return true.  Assume other scenario has its case exhausted.

The reason you get completely different results is because you *completely flip the logic* of the program.  Here's your code, in English again:

- Looping across all characters of a string, starting at 1 and going until 1 before its end

  - If the character at a given position *i* is `*`:

    - If the characters a position before and a position after are not equal:

      - Return true.
- Return false.  Assume other scenario has its case exhausted.

You haven't made `false` the default return option; **you've inverted the entire program's logic.**  Consider the empty string, which is a valid test case.  Your code said that this is invalid, when there's no asterisk to be had in the string (which would be a strange false positive).

Comment: You wrote : "If the characters a position before and a position after are equal" in both cases, but it is != results false  **VS** == results true .

Comment: @Gery:  Good catch.  I'll revise this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st case works because it returns true only if the `*` is preceded and followed by the same character or if the `string` doesn't contain a `*` at all.

The 2nd case doesn't work because it returns true if it contains at-least one `*` and first instance of `*` is preceded and followed by the same characters regardless of next instances of `*`. So if a blank string is passed it should return true but it instead returns false because it doesn't contain `*`. If another string `*xa*a*b` is passed the second program will return true because the instance of `*` follows the convention. The 2nd Program will return true right away, ignoring all the `*` after the it's first appearance.

Comment: Second program still loops through all `*`, so **any** instance of same char would return `true`.